# Any simple way that concurrent consumers can share data in Camel?

Tags: apache-camel

We have a typical scenario in which we have to load-balance a set of cloned consumer applications, each running in a different physical server. Here, we should be able to dynamically add more servers for scalability.

We were thinking of using the round-robin load balancing here. But we don't want a long-running job in the server cause a message to wait in its queue for consumption.

To solve this, we thought of having 2 concurrentConsumers configured for each of the server application. When an older message is processed by a thread and a new  message arrives, the latter will be consumed from the queue by the second thread. While processing the new message, the second thread has to check a class (global) variable shared by the threads. If 'ON', it can assume that one thread is active (ie. job is already in progress). In that case, it re-routes the message back to its source queue. But if the class variable is 'OFF', it can start the job with the message data.

The jobs are themselves heavyweight and so we want only one job to be processed at a time. That's why the second thread re-routes the message, if another thread is active.

So, the question is 'Any simple way that concurrent consumers can share data in Camel?'. Or, can we solve this problem in an entirely different way?

Answer (score 0):

For a JMS broker like ActiveMQ you should be able to simply use concurrent listeners on the same queue. It should do round robin but only with the consumers that are idle. So basically this should just work. Eventually you have to set the prefetch size to 1 as prefetch might cause a consumer to take messages even when a long running process will block them.